# php base64_decode , unable to determine what type of separators in decoded string

Tags: php, base64

I'm able to to decode below string using phpbase64_decode function, how ever it seems i cant get to know what type of separator character used in the output decoded string,  any idea what is these separators characters ?

**PHP Base64_encoded string**

ChBob3cgZmFzdCBhcmUgeW91EhVob3cgZmFzdCBjYW4geW91IHR5cGUSG3doYXQgaXMgYSBmYXN0IHR5cGluZyBzcGVlZBIYd2hhdCBpcyBhIGdvb2Qgd3BtIHNwZWVkEh1pcyA2MCB3cG0gYSBnb29kIHR5cGluZyBzcGVlZBIraG93IHRvIHR5cGUgd2l0aG91dCBsb29raW5nIGF0IHRoZSBrZXlib2FyZBISd2hhdCBpcyBjcG0gdHlwaW5nEiF3aGF0IGlzIHRoZSBhdmVyYWdlIHNob3J0aGFuZCB3cG0SJHdoYXQgaXMgYSBnb29kIHR5cGluZyBzcGVlZCBmb3Igam9icxgAIhCSCt0HyzW3XsR-52rqa8UN

**PHP Base64_decoded string**

```
how fast are youhow fast can you typewhat is a fast typing speedwhat is a good wpm speedis 60 wpm a good typing speed+how to type without looking at the keyboardwhat is cpm typing!what is the average shorthand wpm$what is a good typing speed for jobs"
5^yںC
```

Comment: Maybe it's a non-printable character. Have you tried checking its [ASCII value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)? It could be a [#29, group separator](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/group-separator-ascii-code-29.html) or a #30 record separator.

Comment: Btw, apparently that string is not valid base64. At least I tried to parse it using several online converters, but they failed.

Comment: make sure to copy the full string till the end of it (which is -52rqa8UN)  for some reasons when you just double click the string its not being fully copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://conv.darkbyte.ru/ which can show the results in a hex view. Given the fact that your string ends in garbage (I think) and that some other converters don't want to convert your string at all, I doubt if it is fully and valid base64. It looks like it's messed up a bit. At least the dash should not be in there.

The characters in between are hex 12 and 15.
Looking up those characters in http://www.asciitable.com/ it doesn't make much sense. They are 'device control 1' and 'negative acknowledge'. I have no idea why those characters would be in there, except when it's output from some specific hardware like a scanner, or a stream to specific hardware like a printer.

One possibility is that the characters are accidentally converted from a different base. Coincidentally, 12 and 15 *octal* result in a newline and a carriage return, which would kinda make sense as a separator, although they are in the wrong order then.. Also weird, because the decoded string starts with an actual line feed, not a scrambled one.

So maybe the characters are misinterpreted on an earlier level, before encoding it to base64. Some JavaScript parsers tend to interpret numbers with a leading 0 as octal numbers, so 012 would be interpreted as octal 12.

Anyway, those are the characters and the tool to investigate the rest of your string. To see how they got there, you'll need to debug the code that resulted in this string.

Comment: Thanks Golez, This was really helpful